# Will linq bring back all records from a stored procedure call, and then filter?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Given the EF linq below, will all the records in the stored proc usp_GetTestRecords() come across and then get filtered?

```
    TestRecordsDBEntities dataContext = new TestRecordsDBEntities();
    var tests = dataContext.usp_GetTestRecords();
    var filtered = tests.Where(x => x.GroupId == groupId)
        .OrderByDescending(y => y.Name)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: yes............

Comment: Yes, because the stored procedure call is just another method call, not a call the returns an IEnumerable

Comment: It looks like you're getting all records when you define `tests` (assuming that's what `usp_GetTestRecords()` does) and then filter the results in the next line where you define `filtered`

Comment: If `usp_GetTestRecords()` returns an `IQueryable<T>` of course, that's a different matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** all data will be first *fetched in the memory and then filtered on the client side*. Using stored procedure with EF is not a good idea. You will loose the advantage of lazy,eager or explicit loading here. However if you let EF generate queries for you then it will be compiled will all filters and executed on server

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you may want to consider creating a [table value function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) rather than stored proc. The advantage here is that result-set of the function can be joined with other tables on the server side. The disadvantage is that you are limited in terms of what you can do inside of the function and the database does not have access to indexes for the function results that you could with indexed views.

See more about using TVS with EF at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/01/21/table-valued-function-support.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sprocs will allways return all the records affected by te query associated to it. If you want to add a where clause just add a param to your sproc and perform the filtering in sql. Check this for more information [How to pass Parameters to Stored Procedure from Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332013/how-to-pass-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-entity-framework)

Comment: This is my issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/18245567/139698  I have a dynamic pivot query (not shown for simplicity purposes) that I can't get into my gridview